# I am known for believing my Teddy is real

Tags: riddle

> I am known for believing my Teddy is real
>
> I have a girlfriend though she is rarely seen
>
> The reliant one is my greatest rival
>
> Throughout this all I utter barely a word

Who am I?

*Who you are looking for is a person's name, they are fictional.*

Comment: seems like you are new at puzzling. So, lesson number 26: "Give better tile than 'Another who am I riddle','Guess who am I' etc." Also you might want to consider the [tag:movie] tag

Comment: @manshu Ill keep that in mind for next time

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you are

> Mr. Bean

Line by line explanation:

I am known for believing my Teddy is real

> Mr. Bean often pretends to speak with his teddy bear (named Teddy)

I have a girlfriend though she is rarely seen

> Mr. Bean has a sort of girlfriend, Irma Gobb, but she appears rarely in the show

The reliant one is my greatest rival

> This is refering to the Reliant car that is often bumped and crashed by Mr. Bean's car

Throughout this all I utter barely a word

> Mr. Bean basically never speaks

Comment: You are correct, I didnt expect this to be answered 15 minutes after it being posted but oh well, if you could update your answer with the answers to each line that would also be great

Comment: Done! I forgot to do that.

Comment: Great, you got them all, I added MrBeans girlfriends name as well

Answer (score 6):

An answer has already been accepted but I'll post what I thought anyway.

Are you

> Bane

**I am known for believing my Teddy is real**

> Bane has a teddy bear called Osito

**I have a girlfriend though she is rarely seen**

This one doesn't exactly fit

**The reliant one is my greatest rival**

> 'Reliant' makes me think 'Reliant Robin'. Robin / Nightwing is an enemy of Bane's.

**Throughout this all I utter barely a word**

> Bane is a relatively reticent character

Comment: Well, I like the answer, for his girlfriend you can to an extend say Miranda Tate was however bane was more of a father figure for her